# Python: how many times do the values in a list appear in a dictionary of lists?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, counter

Say you have a list of `float` values like this:

`l=[0.1,0.3,0.2]`

And a dictionary of lists like this:
`d1={0:[0.1,0.1,0.1,0.2], 1:[0.1,0.3,0.2], 2:[0.3,0.2,0.1]}`

What would be a Pythonic way of counting how many times each value in `l` appears in the sublists of `d1`?

The intended outcome would be a dictionary of lists like this:

`d2={0.1:[3,1,1], 0.2:[1,1,1], 0.3:[0,1,1]}`

where the key is the value in `l` and the sublist contains the number of occurrences of each value.

Can this be done using `Counter`? The order of the values in the sublists is not important.

NB: this question [is not the same as this other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401904/python-collections-counter-for-a-list-of-dictionaries), where a list of dictionaries is involved.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Collections Counter for a List of Dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401904/python-collections-counter-for-a-list-of-dictionaries)

Comment: This question is about a dictionary of lists though.

Comment: Considering that dictionaries are not ordered, one cannot expect the count for each item to be ordered.

Comment: The order is not important

Comment: What happened when you tried to do this with a counter?  Where is your attempt using another technique?

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: true, but we can sort the keys of `d1`, so there's a reasonably canonical order we could use.

Comment: @DSM True. Only wanted to clarify that from OP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert the lists inside `d1` to `Counter` objects and gather them in a list. That list will then be used to get the number of occurrences of each element of `l` in every sublist while keeping the order:

```
In [12]: counters = [Counter(v) for v in d1.values()]

In [13]: {num: [c[num] for c in counters] for num in l}
Out[13]: {0.1: [3, 1, 1], 0.2: [1, 1, 1], 0.3: [0, 1, 1]}
```