# How can I combine values based on some key in python dict just like SQL GROUP BY

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
L = [{'id':1, 'quantity':1}, {'id':2, 'quantity':2}, {'id':1, 'quantity':3}]
```

I want to add quantity base on id ,

So for the list above I would like the output to be:

```
 [{'id':1,'quantity':4},{'id':2,'quantity':2}]
```

another example:

```
L = [{'id':1, 'quantity':1}, {'id':2, 'quantity':2}, {'id':1, 'quantity':2}, {'id':1, 'quantity':3}]
```

So for the list above I would like the output to be:

```
 [{'id':1, 'quantity':6}, {'id':2, 'quantity':2}]
```

Comment: why's the `id` 4? shouldn't it be `1`?

Comment: because L[0] and L[2] have equal key id =1,so sum of their value of quantity

Comment: but the `id` should've been `1` and not `4`, however looks like someone has edited it for you.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28401904/python-collections-counter-for-a-list-of-dictionaries

Comment: you are right ,that is my spelling errors.sorry for confusing you .

Answer (score 2):

In **python** *"group by"* functionality may be achieved by `itertools.groupby()` function:

```
import itertools

l = [{'id':1, 'quantity':1}, {'id':2, 'quantity':2}, {'id':1, 'quantity':3}]
result = [ {'id': k, 'quantity': sum(_['quantity'] for _ in g)} 
            for k,g in itertools.groupby(sorted(l, key=lambda x:x['id']), key=lambda x:x['id'])]

print(result)
```

The output:

```
[{'id': 1, 'quantity': 4}, {'id': 2, 'quantity': 2}]
```

Comment: but you are traversing the list once for every unique `id` like that, right? That's quite inefficient.

Answer (score 2):

This should do what you want:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def combine(items):
    counts = defaultdict(int)
    for d in items:
        counts[d["id"]] += d["quantity"]

    return [{"id": id, "quantity": q} for id, q in counts.items()]
```

Examples:

```
>>> combine([{'id':1, 'quantity':1}, {'id':2, 'quantity':2}, {'id':1, 'quantity':3}])
[{'quantity': 4, 'id': 1}, {'quantity': 2, 'id': 2}]

>>> combine([{'id':1, 'quantity':1}, {'id':2, 'quantity':2}, {'id':1, 'quantity':2}, {'id':1, 'quantity':3}])
[{'quantity': 6, 'id': 1}, {'quantity': 2, 'id': 2}]
```

This is about as simple and efficient as you're going to get.

Answer (score 1):

convert it to `dataframe` and then back to `dict`

```
import pandas as pd
L = [{'id':1, 'quantity':1}, {'id':2, 'quantity':2}, {'id':1, 'quantity':3}]
output=pd.DataFrame(L).groupby('id')['quantity'].sum().to_dict()
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is properly defined, here I implemented in a intuitive way to achieve this:

```
output = {}
keys=[]
for e in L:
    if e['id'] not in keys:
        keys.append(e['id'])
        output[e['id']] = e['quantity']
    else:
        output[e['id']] += e['quantity']

[{'id':key,'identity':values} for key,values in  output.items()]
```

I was actually wondering that is there any further requirements, for instance, that you need a probably higher efficiency to perform a huge volume of data? If yes, this method seems to be tedious.